# T-SQL - search in filtered JSON array

Tags: json, t-sql, sql-server-2017

SQL Server 2017.

Table `OrderData` has column `DataProperties` where JSON is stored. JSON example stored there:

```
{
 "Input": {
   "OrderId": "abc",
   "Data": [
     {
       "Key": "Files",
       "Value": [
         "test.txt",
         "whatever.jpg"
       ]
     },
     {
       "Key": "Other",
       "Value": [
         "a"
       ]
     }
   ]
 }
}
```

So, it's an object with Input object, which has Data array that's KVP - full of objects with Key string and Value array of strings.

And my problem - I need to query for rows based on values in Files in example JSON - simple LIKE that matches `%text%`.

This query works:

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM OrderData CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(DataProperties,'$.Input.Data') dat
WHERE JSON_VALUE(dat.value, '$.Key') = 'Files' and dat.[key] = 0 
AND JSON_QUERY(dat.value, '$.Value') LIKE '%2%'
```

Problem is that this query is very slow, unsurprisingly.

How to make it faster?

1. I cannot create computed column with JSON_VALUE, because I need to filter in an array.
2. I cannot create computed column with JSON_QUERY on "$.Input.Data" or "$.Input.Data[0].Values" - because I need specific array item in this array with `Key == "Files"`.

I've searched, but it seems that you cannot create computed column that also filters data, like with this attempt:

```
ALTER TABLE OrderData
 ADD aaaTest AS (select JSON_QUERY(dat.value, '$.Value')
 OPENJSON(DataProperties,'$.Input.Data') dat
WHERE JSON_VALUE(dat.value, '$.Key') = 'Files' and dat.[key] = 0 );
```

Error: `Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.`

---

What are my options?

1. Add Files column with an index and use INSERT/UPDATE triggers that populate this column on inserts/updates?
2. Create a view that "computes" this column? Can't add index, will still be slow

So far only option 1. has some merit, but I don't like triggers and maybe there's another option?

Comment: Yes, you'd want to parse the JSON during insert and store those key/value pairs into properly schema'd and indexed tables to make querying more efficient.

Comment: I hope it is a typo, that we once see `"Value"` (singular) and once `"Values"` (plural). Both name an array of values...

Comment: Yes, a typo, fixed, In my case it's singular `Value` with array of values.

Comment: @Lars, okay... So you'll have to correct this in my answer ;-)

Comment: @Jon figures. Can't change JSON to fit computed column, ie move Files array to Input.Data.Files property, will have to use triggers.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something along this:

**Attention**: I've added a `2` to the `text2` to fullfill your filter. And I named both to the plural `"Values"`:

```
DECLARE @mockupTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, DataProperties NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @mockupTable VALUES
(N'{
 "Input": {
   "OrderId": "abc",
   "Data": [
     {
       "Key": "Files",
       "Values": [
         "test2.txt",
         "whatever.jpg"
       ]
     },
     {
       "Key": "Other",
       "Values": [
         "a"
       ]
     }
   ]
 }
}');
```

The query

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM @mockupTable t 
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.DataProperties,'$.Input.Data')
WITH([Key] NVARCHAR(100)
    ,[Values] NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) dat
WHERE dat.[Key] = 'Files'
AND dat.[Values] LIKE '%2%';
```

The main difference is the `WITH`-clause, which is used to return the properties inside an object in a typed way and *side-by-side* (similar to a *naked* `OPENJSON` with a `PIVOT` for all columns - but much better). This avoids expensive JSON methods in your `WHERE`...

**Hint**: As we return the `Value` with `NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON` we can continue with the nested array and might proceed with something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM @mockupTable t 
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.DataProperties,'$.Input.Data')
WITH([Key] NVARCHAR(100)
    ,[Values] NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) dat
WHERE dat.[Key] = 'Files'
--we read the array again with `OPENJSON`:
AND 'test2.txt' IN(SELECT [Value] FROM OPENJSON(dat.[Values]));
```

You might use one more `CROSS APPLY` to add the array's values and filter this at the `WHERE` directly.

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM @mockupTable t 
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.DataProperties,'$.Input.Data')
WITH([Key] NVARCHAR(100)
    ,[Values] NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) dat
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(dat.[Values]) vals
WHERE dat.[Key] = 'Files'
  AND vals.[Value]='test2.txt'
```

Just check it out...

Comment: First example - I need to filter by wildcards, not exact values, and it's still slow without any index. Second example - still slow, I need an index. Full table scan is not an option.

Comment: You need to get your JSON out of a column and into a proper schema with Key/Value or Key/Value(s) and proper indexing if you want to query it quickly

Comment: @Lars, you'll have to find, what is best for you... A `LIKE` with a leading `%` won't use and index anyway. This is always slow... Parsing JSON is - in any case - an expensive operation. The developers did a pretty good job tough... This won't get much faster.

Comment: Trailing % should suffice. Anyways, will go with triggers and an ordinary varchar column and filter by it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Lars, With XML we can use predicates, something along `/Input/Data[Key="Files]/Value`, but this is not (yet) available in json path. XQuery is much better supported, hopefully they will introduce better query support for JSON soon. The first suggestion will be the best you can get on current JSON level...

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I would like to revisit it.  There isn't any mention of how the source table is actually constructed in terms of indexing.  If the original author is still around, can you confirm/deny what indexing strategy you used?  For performant json document queries, I've found that having a table using the COLUMSTORE  indexing strategy yields very performant JSON queries even with large amounts of data.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/store-json-documents-in-sql-tables?view=sql-server-ver15 has an example of different indexing techniques.  For my personal solution I've been using COLUMSTORE albeit on a limited NVARCAHR document size.  It's fast enough for any purposes I have even under millions of rows of decently sized json documents.